# JavaScript var scoping in strict mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope, javascript-engine

So since ES6 all functions are block scoped in strict mode, but "var" ignores block scope, then why code below gives a reference error?

```
'use strict'
function asd() {
  var ssss = 5;
}

console.log(ssss);
//reference error

for (const item of arr) {
  var sss = 5;
}

console.log(sss);
//5
```

Comment: `var ssss` is scoped to only the `asd()` function.

Comment: "*since ES6 all functions are block scoped*" that's not true - ES6 introduces block scope but functions aren't "block scoped" - function scope still exists.